# Scipy: Kmeans and vq how to use them?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

Hi I am trying to use K means and vq implemented in scipy: here more details --> http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html.

The point is that I have a list of [x, 36] where each row is an observation, and each column a field of the observation, so basically each observation is composed by 36 values.

I am trying to cluster them together and to understand which row goes in which cluster. According to the documentation it should be something like this:

```
data_array_n = np.array(data_array)
whitened = whiten(data_array_n)
print "Starting K means"
centroids, distortion = kmeans(whitened, k, iter=1000)

print centroids

idx, distortion = vq(whitened , centroids)
```

but when I check the idx I get completely useless values. 
data_array is a list of x lists in 36 elements.
Thank you for all your help

Comment: Please describe the "completely useless values" in some more detail. Do they match what the documentation promises?

Comment: Sorry, you are right.
For instance if I pass a K=3 I expect to have 3  arrays of 36 dimensions with the coordinates of the centroids. What I get instead is 1 single centroid, no matter how many K I pass.
Moreover the idx should be accordingly to the documentation, an integer between 0 and K, that basically assigns the corresponding row to the proper cluster. What I get instead are values like these:
    [    139733472771528     139733472771528            46314096
            46314096   -2251799813685248   -2251799813685248
   -2251799813685248   -2251799813685248   -2251799813685248 ....

Comment: taking out the whiten function seems to be working properly... would this make sense???

Comment: No, that sounds really strange. `whiten` should return an array of the same shape that you pass in.

Comment: IT should... but as soon as I took away the whiten I get something more related to the specific case, that means and idx array with x elements between 0 and k.
I do not understand what it could be wrong

Comment: Be careful with 36 dimensions. K-means doesn't scale very well to high dimensionality (squared Euclidean degrades), plus if you have e.g. sparse or discrete data that also tends to produce not too meaningful results. In particular when k << d.

Comment: In a way I succeeded in getting some values, now I am analyzing them... I have seen papers where they are using K means with Euclidean distance over 54 dimensions...
I think that the type of data that I have, when whitened, get completely  meaningless since there are many 0 in each vector. I am analyzing network traffic so when the machines are off I get a lot of 0 and I cannot really get rid of them.
More suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depended on the way the whitening function is built...

```
def whiten(obs)
     std_dev = std(obs, axis=0)
     return obs / std_dev
```

that does not make any sense since it is by default computed on the first column, and in my case was always 0 since there is no data at that time.
Fixed making my own whitening function, that returns the numpy array whitened over the std of the whole data set and not only on the first axis!

```
def whiten(obs)
     std_dev = std(obs)
     return obs / std_dev
```

Way better results obtained from a quantization error of 1000+ to 0.003 with the same iterations!